# How to solve this multiple where conditions(field_ids and values)?

Tags: mysql, sql

### select value = Hemraj and value = pal,  where field_id = 3 and where field_id = 4;

```html
how to solve this query?

table structure :

field_id = 3 value = Hemraj
field_id = 4 value = Pal
field_id = 3 value = Subhankar
field_id = 4 value = Chaole
field_id = 3 value = Suman
field_id = 4 value = Pal
field_id = 3 value = Akash
field_id = 4 value = Dutta
field_id = 3 value = Hemraj
field_id = 4 value = Pal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT value FROM engine4_user_fields_values 
where field_id=3 
   or field_id=4 
   or field_id=5 
   or field_id=6 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use IN operator

```
SELECT value FROM engine4_user_fields_values 
where field_id IN (3,4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple WHERE conditons.

```
SELECT value FROM engine4_user_fields_values 
    WHERE field_id1=3 AND field_id2=4 AND ....
```

a good example is given in the link

[Multiple where conditions](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/9/3/13/multiple-where-conditions)

Comment: Note that `field_id=3 AND field_id=4` is a contradiction: either `field_id` has the value 3 or it has the value 4. If your `SELECT` ever returned a record, I would check the column for schizophrenia (or file a bug at https://bugs.mysql.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Actually i meant the field ids are different. I understand my fault. answer edited.